# How do I assign value of the clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following on jsfiddle. What I need to accomplish is when I click on a button the respective value is inserted in the blank.

https://jsfiddle.net/aminbaig/jefee77L/

Here is the Code:

HTML:

```html
There is <span id="title">___________</span> wrong with this world!
<p>
  Choose the appropriate word
</p>
<input type="submit" id="myTextField" value="something" onclick="change()" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn1" value="Truck" onclick="change()" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn2" value="Trash" onclick="change()" />
```

Javascript:

```js
function change() {

  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }

  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

**JS**

get the value of the button from the function parameter

```
function change(value) {
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = value;
}
```

**HTML**

change button `type='submit'` to `type='button'`, Also pass the value as the function parameter

```
<input type="button" id="myTextField" value="something" onclick="change(this.value)" />
<input type="button" id="byBtn1" value="Truck" onclick="change(this.value)" />
<input type="button" id="byBtn2" value="Trash" onclick="change(this.value)" />
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lw1e6hc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use like this `onclick="change(this.value)"` .send the value of the input via `click` function

```js
function change(val) {
  if (val.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = val;

}
```

```html
There is <span id="title">___________</span> wrong with this world!
<p>
  Choose the appropriate word
</p>
<input type="submit" id="myTextField" value="something" onclick="change(this.value)" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn1" value="Truck" onclick="change(this.value)" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn2" value="Trash" onclick="change(this.value)" />
```